# Quickly determine when npm overrides are no longer necessary

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

To assist in keeping sub-dependencies up-to-date as an open vulnerability works its way through the SDLC of repositories (or doesn't in the case of unsupported packages), we have the opportunity to use npm's [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) or yarn's [resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).

In the case where the vulnerability resolution makes it way through the dependency chain and the override becomes unnecessary, it becomes a maintenance challenge to know when.

What is a relatively painless way to validate when an override is immaterial, or even outdated/detrimental?

A few ideas off the top of my head:

- a `git bisect`-like function that runs a deterministic npm install with and without each override
- an improved override schema with an assertion that allows one to specify when the package is no longer necessary (e.g. when the specific CVE is no longer present or perhaps an npm audit passes)